# Replacing from match to end-of-line

Tags: regex, sed

This should be incredibly easy but I can't get it to work.  I just want to use ***`sed`*** to replace from one string to the end of a line.  For example if I have the following data file:

```
   one  two  three  five
   four two  five five six
   six  one  two seven four
```

and I want to replace from the word "two" through the end of the line with the word "BLAH" ending up with the output:

```
   one BLAH
   four BLAH
   six one BLAH
```

wouldn't that just be:

```
   sed -e 's/two,$/BLAH/g'
```

I'm not the best at regex to maybe that's the problem

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This should do what you want:

`sed 's/two.*/BLAH/'`

```
$ echo "   one  two  three  five
>    four two  five five six
>    six  one  two seven four" | sed 's/two.*/BLAH/'
   one  BLAH
   four BLAH
   six  one  BLAH
```

The `$` is unnecessary because the `.*` will finish at the end of the line anyways, and the `g` at the end is unnecessary because your first match will be the first `two` to the end of the line.

Answer (score 18):

Use this, two`<anything any number of times><end of line>`

```
's/two.*$/BLAH/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

awk

```
awk '{gsub(/two.*/,"")}1' file
```

Ruby

```
ruby -ne 'print $_.gsub(/two.*/,"")' file
```